# How to handle multi language website in jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I have website which supports English and French.I have already created script for website in English but now they want me to test against french website.So how can i extended my script that asssertions does not fail i test script any of those languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add flexibility to your Assertions so they would check English **OR** French word presence in the response.

For instance if you want to use a single assertion to check whether there is `Welcome` OR `Bienvenue` word in the response you can combine them using pipe as follows:

```
Welcome|Bienvenue
```

As per [How to Use JMeter Assertions in 3 Easy Steps](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide Response Assertion in "Contains" and "Matches" mode accepts Perl5-style regular expressions so you should have enough flexibility to be able to check both English and French website versions.

[image: Response Assertion 2 clauses]

Comment: so if have more languages so i can simply add others using pipe?

Comment: how can i use regular expression extractor to use with those.

Comment: You can use the same approach with regular expressions. Any other language can be added via pipe sign

Answer (score 0):

### In short

Your tests should be language-agnostic, especially performance-/load-tests.

### Explanation

UI tests should use generic selectors such as tags `<p>, <div>, <table>`, element Id's `<div id="basket">` or CSS classes `<p class="message">` for looking up elements. As you're using JMeter, I assume you're on some sort of performance-/load-tests. If so, then you want to look most likely for some action elements to progress your tests.

If you cannot omit some language dependency (for example localized URL-paths), I would suggest using JMeter variables that are set according to the language you're testing with. See [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) for details

In contrast to performance tests, acceptance or general web UI tests would incorporate testing of some labels. Selenium or other HTML capturing tests are usually backed by some test code written by you or your team. That code can rely on resource bundles, translations, etc. so you can test for the correct labels.

HTH, Mark